# Word Order - は and が Particles

Tags: grammar, particles

Today I learn that word order is not very strict in Japanese. You could change the order of noun phrases with no loss of meaning, as long as the correct particles are used.
I've learned this with the subject, object, and location particles: が、を、で

Example:

> なおみが　デパートで　セーターを　買いました。
>
> デパートで　なおみが　セーターを　買いました。

Question: Does the topic marker は conserve the independence of word order on the meaning of a sentence? Could the grammatical topic be used interchangeably with the subject? If in the previous example...

> なおみは　デパートで　セーターを　買いました。
>
> デパートで　なおみは　セーターを　買いました。

Comment: Somewhat related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/13753/splicing-%e3%81%a7%e3%81%82%e3%82%8b-with-a-topic